# Trying to install torch for unity mlagents in the virtual enveiroment

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, pip, pytorch

When i enter the command:

pip3 install torch~=1.7.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

just like the manual at

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/develop/docs/Installation.md

says, i get this error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch~=1.7.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch~=1.7.1

My pip is on version 23.0, python 3.11.1

I tried a bunch of different ways to do this, even from the torch website, but nothing seems to work, i still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

`~=1.7.1` means `>= 1.7.1, == 1.7.*`.

But as far as I can tell, the *PyTorch* releases in this version range do not support Python 3.11. You are probably following instructions that are quite old.

You would need to instruct *pip* to install newer releases of *PyTorch*. Or use an older Python version (probably `3.7` or `3.8` which are quite old and heave nearly reached end of life).

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work, one more question, do you know how to create a virtual environment with an older version of python? I'm just following this https://youtu.be/zPFU30tbyKs?t=244 tutorial, is there maybe an argument that can make it use an older version

Comment: To create a virtual environment for Python 3.7 you need to install Python 3.7 first. Then do `python3.7 -m venv path/to/new/venv`.